# How to change value before page refresh using Javascript?

Tags: javascript, jquery

I want to change variable value before refresh page.

My main goal is to store URLs into array every 3 seconds.
Storing URLs working fine but when the page gets refresh the index[ind] and array[urllist] become null. i want to change the ind ,urllist length before refresh.Please tell me the final solution for this.

```
   <html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head>
    <script>
        var urllist = [];
        var ind = 0;
        var myVar;
        myVar = setInterval(Geturlfun, 3000);
        function Geturlfun() {
            var pageURL = window.location.href;
            if (urllist[ind - 1] == pageURL) {

            } else {
                urllist[ind] = pageURL;                    
                ind = ind + 1;
                alert(pageURL);
            }
        }
        function goBkHist(a) {
            var l_ref = ind - 2;
            if (l_ref != 0) {
                var pageURL2 = urllist[l_ref];
                ind = l_ref + 1;
                alert(pageURL2);
                loadUrl(pageURL2);
            }
        }
        function goFdHist(a) {
            var l_ref_2 = ind;
            var pageURL2 = urllist[l_ref_2];
            ind = l_ref_2 + 1;
            alert(pageURL2);
            loadUrl(pageURL2);
        }
        function loadUrl(newLocation) {
            window.location = newLocation;
            location.reload();
            return true;
        }
    </script>
</head>
<body>
    <input type="button" value="BACK " onclick="goBkHist(-1)" />
    <input type="button" value="FORWARD" onclick="goFdHist(1)" />
</body>
</html>
```

I tried below code for refreshing change. But it displays text message in alert box. I don't want to show any alert box. I want to run function or change values without display popup.

```
window.onunload = function (e) {
                var dialogText = '0';
                e.returnValue = dialogText;
                return dialogText;
            };
```

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Remember that refreshing a page would reset the state of the DOM. So you need to save the information on either client side or server side before you refresh and retrieve the information after completion. You may wanna look at localStorage option

Comment: You'll need to persist the data so that it can live beyond a single page request. Web Storage could help you here.

Answer (score 0):

On a page refresh the DOM is reloaded deleting any varible data you once had. So you would need somewhere to store the data. Such as a webstorage or database etc.

Have a look at this -  http://www.w3schools.com/html/html5_webstorage.asp